# Batch-update with ServiceStack webservice

Tags: c#, servicestack

How would you implement a batch update over a REST service if we have multiple changed properties?

Lets say we have an administrator managing 100 client computers in his software. Some of the computers changed their location and some got deleted. Other ones got a new description, etc. So it's not just `set location = 1 for ids {1,5,8}`.

Is it necessary to make multiple service calls for each change type or is there a possibility I don't see right now?

Update:
It's not just to update one or more records to a given value but the combination of different update scenarios.

- `Update` computers with `ids [1,5,8]` to `locationId=4`
- `Delete` computer with `ids [7,9]`
- `Create` a new computer with `id [10]` and `locationId=7`

This is not uncommon if the client program manages a bunch of records (here computers) and the clicks on "save" for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'd do it like this:

```
[Route("/computer/{ComputerId}", "POST")]
public class UpdateComputerRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int ComputerId { get; set; }
}

[Route("/computer/{ComputerId}", "DELETE")]
public class DeleteComputerRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    public int ComputerId { get; set; }
}

[Route("/computers", "POST")]
public class BatchRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    public List<UpdateComputerRequest> UpdateRequests { get; set; }
    public List<DeleteComputerRequest> DeleteRequests { get; set; }
}

public class ComputerLocationService : Service
{
    public void Post(UpdateComputerRequest request)
    {
        PostImpl(request);
    }

    public void Post(DeleteComputerRequest request)
    {
        DeleteImpl(request);
    }

    public void Post(BatchRequest request)
    {
        request.UpdateRequests.ForEach(PostImpl);
        request.DeleteRequests.ForEach(DeleteImpl);
    }

    private void PostImpl(UpdateComputerRequest request)
    {
        // do stuff...
    }

    private void DeleteImpl(DeleteComputerRequest deleteComputerRequest)
    {
        // delete
    }
}
```

there is no create, but should be clear how to do it...

Comment: That totally makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to account for that scenario you need to write a service that accepts an array of the Ids in a request and then processes the 'batch', such as below. I have written two routes, and these accept a single update, or a batch of updates.

```cs
// Update a location with single computer
[Route("/Location/{LocationId}", "POST")]
public class UpdateLocationRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int ComputerId { get; set; }
}

// Update a location with multiple computers
[Route("/Location/{LocationId}/Multiple", "POST")]
public class UpdateMultipleLocationsRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int[] ComputerIds { get; set; }
}    

public class ComputerLocationService : Service
{
    public void Post(UpdateLocationRequest request)
    {
        UpdateLocation(request.LocationId, request.ComputerId);
    }

    public void Post(UpdateMultipleLocationsRequest request)
    {
        // Multiple computers updated by calling the handler many times.
        foreach(int computerId in request.ComputerIds)
            UpdateLocation(request.LocationId, computerId);
    }

    // Method for handling updating one location
    private void UpdateLocation(int locationId, int computerId)
    {
        // Logic to perform the update
    }
}
```

So to make a single update I would POST this JSON to /Location/1

```js
{ "ComputerId": 10 }
```

But to make a batch update I would POST this JSON to /Location/1/Multiple

```js
{ "ComputerIds": [1,5,8] }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, that's not the point I was missing, I'm afraid. What would you do to update the ids [1,5,8] to location=4 AND delete [7,9] AND insert a new item {id=10, locationId=7} in one request.

Comment: @TheBert That's not a feature supported out of the box. You would need to create some sort of request proxy.

Comment: Of course not, I understand. But I'm still searching for that pattern what you described as "sort of request proxy".

Answer (score 1):

Javascrit Code:

```
        // send AJAX request
        var data = new Array();
        var checkedKeyword = {
            "Keyword": "1",
            "TotalNum": 100,
            "State": "stop crawl",
            "Updatetime": "2015-02-15 23:22:06",
            "IsChecked": true
        };
        data.push(checkedKeyword);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/keywords/processchecked",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "CheckedKeywords": data }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                //
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //
            }
        })

    });
```

C# Code:

```
[Route("/api/keywords/processchecked", "POST")]
public class RequestCheckedKeywords : IReturn<Response>
{
    public List<CheckedKeyword> CheckedKeywords { get; set; }
}

public class CheckedKeyword
{
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public int TotalNum { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Updatetime { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class KeywordsServices : Service
{
    public Response Post(RequestCheckedKeywords request)
    {
        return new Response { Result = 1, Message = "" };
    }
}
```

the javascript code and c# code work very well.
I can get value of RequestCheckedKeywords request, It is right from javascript.

Comment: two very useful links:

Binding complex object to request DTO
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/77EXmIjkrBY

How do I send an array to servicestack with javascript?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/OmFN4zeH48Q

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Keywords/Multiple",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "ComputerIds": [1,5,8] }), 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            //
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //
        }
    })

[Route("/api/Keywords/Multiple", "POST")]
public class UpdateMultipleLocationsRequest : IReturn<Response>
{
    public int[] ComputerIds { get; set; }
} 

public Response Post(UpdateMultipleLocationsRequest request)
        {
            return new Response { Result = 1, Message = "..." };
        }
```

this code works well.